# ServerSelectionTimeoutError( pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 147.234.32.246:27017

Tags: windows, mongodb, server, pymongo, rdp

I try to connect remotely to mongodb server from pycharm(with RDP).
this is thefunction that i run:

```
cluster = MongoClient("mongodb://admin:Passw0rd!@147.234.32.246:27017/NEG")
db = cluster["NEG"]

for word in Setting.dictionary_global.keys():
    if word in db.list_collection_names():
        collection = db[word]
        for file in Setting.dictionary_global[word].keys():
            if collection.find({"url":Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].url}):
                continue
            num_of_appearance = len(Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].indexes.get(word))
            post = {"url": file, "title": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].title,
                    "description": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].description,"word in page": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].indexes,"appearance": num_of_appearance, "date modified": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].time}
            collection.insert_one(post)

    else:
        collection = db.create_collection(word)
        for file in Setting.dictionary_global[word].keys():

            #print(Setting.dictionary_global)
            num_of_appearance = len(Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].indexes.get(word))
            post = {"url": file, "title": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].title,
                    "description": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].description,"word in page": Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].indexes, "appearance": num_of_appearance, "date modified":Setting.dictionary_global[word][file].time}
            collection.insert_one(post)
```

and i get this error:

'''

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/edend/PycharmProjects/pythonProject11/main.py", line 118, in 
crawler.start()
File "C:/Users/edend/PycharmProjects/pythonProject11/main.py", line 110, in start
insertDB()
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\DB.py", line 10, in insertDB
if word in db.list_collection_names():
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 863, in list_collection_names
for result in self.list_collections(session=session, **kwargs)]
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 825, in list_collections
return self.__client._retryable_read(
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1460, in _retryable_read
server = self._select_server(
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1278, in _select_server
server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 241, in select_server
return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 199, in select_servers
server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
File "C:\Users\edend\PycharmProjects\pythonProject11\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 147.234.32.246:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5ff3d15a2dcaa1e4fb3db4cd, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('147.234.32.246', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('147.234.32.246:27017: timed out')>]>

'''

please help me im stuck and iv'e try everything
thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Common causes:

- MongoDB server is not running
- MongoDB server is running on a different port
- No connectivity between client and server (can you ping)
- mongod.conf is configure to only allow local connections by default (set bind_ip_all?)